# Javascript -Object construction and Utilization - to get deep understand

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, object

Could someone tell me:

1. how to choose an object construction based on different development scenarios.?
2. which is a good pattern so far for the development when compared to another pattern?
3. if you have a chance to develop a complete project for Banking/ Social Networking/ online purchase (like Amazon, eBay), etc, which one would you use and why.?

This is just to get enough understanding from ground level.

**1. Object constructor:**

```
var person = new Object();
person.name = "Demo name",
person.getName = function(){
  return this.name ; 
};
```

Using Object.create() method:
var a = Object.create(null);

**2. Literal constructor:**

```
var person = { 
  name : "Demo name",
  getName : function (){
   return this.name
  } 
}
```

**3. Function constructor:**

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name
  this.getName = function(){
    return this.name
  } 
}
```

**4. Prototype:**

```
function Person(){};
Person.prototype.name = "Demo name";
```

**5. Function/Prototype combination:**

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
} 
Person.prototype.getName = function(){
  return this.name
}
```

**6. Singleton:**

```
var person = new function(){
  this.name = "Demo name"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is a no-go. It has no benefits over a literal, and is just way slower & less readable.
2. Is always a good choice.

   ```
   const user = { name: "Jonas", session: 1234 };
   ```
3. should be used instead of 2. if you have additional logic when setting up an object (e.g. if a user gets created, generate a session for him), or if you have to create a certain object at multiple places. However I'm not in favor of the `new` operator, I'd just do:

   ```
   function createUser(name) {
     return { name, session: createSession() }
   }

   function logout(user) {
    user.session = undefined;
   }
   ```
4. not sure what that should be, having properties on the prototype rarely makes sense.
5. Is a good choice if you are in favor of OOP, however nowadays I'd use the `class` syntax for that, cause its way easier to read (especially for programmers from another language). By moving methods into the prototype, they get shared between instances, which will reduce memory & performance costs if a lot of instances get created.

   ```
   class User {
     constructor(name) {
       this.name = name;
     }
     login() {
       this.session = 1234;
     }
   }
   ```
6. makes never sense, go with 1. instead